# How to handle my JSON data in jQuery Ajax success callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

If I have a ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: function(json_data){
    //What's the efficient way to extract the JSON data and get the value
  }
});
```

Server returned to my js the following **JSON** data

```
{"contact":[{"address":[{"city":"Shanghai","street":"Long
            Hua Street"},{"city":"Shanghai","street":"Dong Quan
            Street"}],"id":"huangyim","name":"Huang Yi Ming"}]}
```

In my jQuery AJAX success callback function, how to extract the value of "**name**", value of "**address**" (which is a **list of object**) elegantly?

I am not experienced with jQuery and JSON data handling in javascript. So, I would like to ask some suggestions on how to handle this data efficiently. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A JSON string gets parsed into a JavaScript object/array. So you can access the values like you access any object property, array element:

```
var name = json_data.contact[0].name;
var addresses = json_data.contact[0].address;
```

Do access the values inside each address, you can iterate over the array:

```
for(var i = addresses.length; i--;) {
    var address = addresses[i];
    // address.city
    // address.street
    // etc
}
```

If you have not so much experience with JavaScript, I suggest to [read this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide).