# How to send a json string back to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I need to send some data to an external php page and that page has to send the required data back to jQuery. My question is how can I send the data from the external page back to jQuery on the page that send it.

This is the jQuery code that sends the data to the external page:

```
function LoadImageData(url)
{    
    $.ajax({
      url: 'get_image_data.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {'url': url },
      success: SetTag()
    }); 
}
```

This is the PHP code htat receives the data and is required to send some data back:

```
<?php
require_once('FaceRestClient.php');

$apiKey = '**********************';
$apiSecret = '**********************';
$api = new FaceRestClient($apiKey, $apiSecret);

$active_url = $_POST['url'];
$photos = $api->faces_detect($active_url);

return $photos;
?>
```

So my problem is, how can I send the data backto jQuery. Just a simple return does not seem to work.

Thanks in Advance,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One would think the REST API would give you JSON, but you need to check if it's valid JSON (JSONP is not valid here) ?

You could just drop the dataType in your Ajax function and let jQuery figure it out, that way atleast you'll get something back if it's not valid JSON.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'get_image_data.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {'url': url }
    }).done(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
    }).fail(function() {
       console.log('Your ajax just failed');
});
```

Open the console, and see what is printed

At the end of a PHP function I tend to do :

```
exit(json_encode($someData));
```

To return the data as JSON, but anything that prints the data is ok.

Comment: It still states that the $_POST['url'] is undefined

Comment: @DijkeMark - You're probably not setting it as a `POST` request, try `$_GET['url']`, as that is probably the standard method for JSON.

Comment: And that was indeed what went wrong. it now gives the right data back. Thanks man

Comment: edited my answer, that way you can use a POST request if thats preffered, but JSON will always default to GET, and JSONP only supports GET.

Answer (score 3):

You need to echo the resulting JSON:

```
echo $photos;
```

If `$photos` is not already JSON, use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode):

```
echo json_encode( $photos);
```

Comment: But how do I use it back in jQuery then? When I try to insert a variable in the success method as a parameter it gives an error saying the the given parameter is undevined.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661647/how-to-handle-my-json-data-in-jquery-ajax-success-callback).

Answer (score 1):

you need to echo

```
echo $photos;
```

and as metntoned by @nickb if $photo is not already a json then convert it into json first and then echo.

```
echo json_encode($photos)
```

in jQuery if you want to fetch the data

```
onSuccess: function(data, status) {
    //var data contains the returned json.
}
```

Comment: But how do I use it back in jQuery then? When I try to insert a variable in the success method as a parameter it gives an error saying the the given parameter is undevined.

Comment: FireBug now gives an error stating the $_POST['url'] is undefined. Why is that?

Comment: change `$active_url = $_POST['url'];` to `$active_url = isset($_POST['url']) ? $_POST['url'] : '';`

Comment: you are not checking wether POST value of url is set or not, even if it is not set it will try executing which will result into error.

Comment: That sounds logic, except I am sending an url, because I put it in the ajax request. data: {'url': url }. SO why does it still say the url is undefined?

Comment: why you defined `$active_url = $_POST['url'];` your script expects the value to be set in `$_POST['url']`. through POST request, and since the value is not set it is showing you the error

Comment: The `$_POST['url']` value is set in the `$.ajax` call's `data: {'url' : url}`, however it is good form to use a `isset()` before trying to access the value.

Comment: So I need to change to $_POST['url'] to a string or something?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
echo json_encode( $photos);
```