# How to properly use parseJSON?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send a json string back to jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454516/how-to-send-a-json-string-back-to-jquery)

I need to run **myquery.php** and then I need to use outputs of this php code inside the JavaScript function **createChartControl**. Below is my complete code. The problem is that Alert message (`alert(returned_array)`) does not appear, and the function **createChartControl** is not executed. I separately tested **myquery.php** and it works fine.

```
<script>
function updateList(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "myquery.php",
        type: 'GET',  
        data: { query: "SELECT tm FROM schedule WHERE val='BT009';" }, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { 
                 var returned_array = $.parseJSON(data);
                 alert(returned_array);
                 createChartControl('schedule', returned_array);
        }
   })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    updateList();
});
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function createChartControl(htmlDiv1,data)
{
//...
}
</script>


<?php
include_once 'include/connect_db.php';

    $query = $_GET['query'];    

    $condb = connectDB();
    $result=execute_query($query);
    closeDB($condb);

    $rows = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $rows[] = $row['tm'];
    }   

    return $rows;
?>
```

**UPDATE**: Still says: Your ajax just failed

```
function updateList(){
   $.ajax({
          url: 'myquery.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {'query': "SELECT tm FROM schedule WHERE val='BT009';" }
        }).done(function(data) {
           console.log(data);
//         createChartControl('schedule', returned_array);
        }).fail(function() {
           console.log('Your ajax just failed');
    });
}
```

**myquery.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'include/connect_db.php';

if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
    $query = $_POST['query'];   

    echo($query);

    $condb = connectDB();
    $result=execute_query($query);
    closeDB($condb);

    $rows = array();

    if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result)) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $rows[] = $row['tm'];
        }
    }   

    echo json_encode($rows);
}
?>
```

Comment: You have to explicitly convert the return array to a JSON string. (Also, I hope that this is some sort of experiment and not real code for a real application, because you've got a serious security problem in there.)

Comment: You are not returning JSON from  your PHP.

Comment: Wait, is this php file the same php file you are making request to? Then it will respond with the full html and it's not valid JSON... consider making a separate PHP file that just echoes JSON.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that you don't use it in this context. If you specify `dataType: 'json'` on a jQuery AJAX call, it will automatically parse the response as JSON.

If the parsing is successful (the server returned valid JSON) then the resulting object is passed to the `success` callback function. If the parsing fails, the `error` callback function is executed (if one has been specified).